# What's the name of an anime with a girl who lives in a farm and takes care of these animals which are like Komodo Dragons?

Tags: kemono-no-souja-erin

The girl has green hair. There's some kind of musical instrument in the anime, like a flute or something. She lives in a farm and takes care of these animals which are then used for war as mounts.

I started watching this anime a long time ago but stopped midway, so now I want to finish the rest of it. If someone here can help me, I'll be very grateful :)

Answer (score 10):

The anime is [**Kemono no Souja Erin**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5420/Kemono_no_Souja_Erin).

[image]

Description from MAL:

> Erin is a young girl who lives with her mother in a village which raises war-lizards, called Touda. We see her daily life, which changes as she grows up. Meanwhile, there is growing tension between the two provinces of the country she lives in.

Comment: @Breno If this answered your question, you can click the green check mark to accept it. You and Tsugumori-704 will both get some reputation.